# Animation On Magnifying Glass with Jquery

Tags: jquery, hover

I have done an animation on a magnifying glass to move on hover, however i have no conflicts and im not sure why its not working.

http://www.kirstymarks.com/

Please see below my code:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ie8 .image-info').css( 'opacity', '0' );
    if ( $('#ie8 .image-info').length ){
            $('.entry-image').hover( function(){
                $(this).find('.image-info').css( 'opacity', '1' );
            }, function(){
                $(this).find('.image-info').css( 'opacity', '0' );
            } );
        };
});
$('.thumbnailwrap .readmore').hover(
            function(){
                $(this).find('span').stop(true,true).animate( { 'top' : '-24px', 'opacity' : '0' }, 150, function(){
                    $(this).css( { 'top' : '86px' } ).animate( { 'top' : '9px', 'opacity' : '1' }, 150 );
                } );
            }, function(){
                $(this).find('span').css( { 'top' : '9px', 'opacity' : '1' } ).stop(true,true).animate( { 'top' : '46px', 'opacity' : '0' }, 150, function(){
                    $(this).css( { 'top' : '-24px', 'opacity' : '1' } ).animate( { 'top' : '9px' }, 150 );
                } );
            }
        );
```

Pointers are appreciated guys, i dont want the answer, i would love to educate myself on how i have gone wrong with the above.

The example what i wanted to recreate was this:-

http://elegantthemes.com/preview/Origin/

Comment: Try putting the hover function inside `$(document).ready` function?

Comment: Define "not working."

Comment: as in on hover it supposed to fly up and come back as per the the css function , and billy, would that be wise?

Comment: Well, I pasted your whole hover function into the console on your page and it works fine so that seems to be the problem.

Comment: Although, I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GntL/) and it works fine either way. Not too sure what to make of this.

Comment: update- changed jsfiddle settings to put in `<head>` (as I assume you have), as it was onLoad by default. Updated fiddle in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankyou to Connor in JS Chat for the answer. This is what i was looking for:-

```
$(function() {
$('.readmore').hover(function() {
    $('span').stop().animate({
        top: '-24px',
        opacity: 0
    }, 150, function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: '86px'
        }).animate({
            top: '9px',
            opacity: 1
        }, 150);
    });    
}, function() {
    $(this).find('span').css({
        top: '9px',
        opacity: 1
    }).stop().animate({
        top: '46px',
        opacity: 0
    }, 150, function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: '-24px',
            opacity: 1
        }).animate({
            top: '9px'
        }, 150);
    });
});
});
```

Example of this :-

http://jsfiddle.net/rusticblonde/T9Gw7/25/

Comment: Please explain your answer.. what have you changed?

Comment: Hi Billy, this is what i was looking for, and it works. The example you gave me was great, but it didnt really explain to me how to animate it, the above was the example i required

Comment: But there's no difference.. The reason why your code wasn't working was because (*See my answer*)

Comment: Sorry - there is a difference - it's all inside `$(function(){` (The same as `$(document).ready` - and the same as my answer)

Comment: Billy, sorry if i have offended you, i didnt mean to. I merely posted the answer to the question, unfortunately i am not very well trained on jquery and learning

Comment: Just annoyed because my answer is correct and not to mention your one is the same. Trying to help but for some reason your just ignoring my suggestion?

Comment: Hi Billy, Sorry to be blunt here. Your answer, granted may seem correct to you, but to me it was using a .css call where myself was using an animate call? Maybe if im wrong here but i believe these are two different functions of jquery? I posted the code and an example as this is what i wanted to recreate. The example, you provided was changing the colour of the div, rather than helping me find out where my animation had gone wrong. Sorry if i have offended you.

Comment: Have you read my answer??? I changed it to use `.animate` - it's not the point! **The reason your code did not work was because your *`.hover`*** **function needed to be inside your `$(document).ready` function**

Answer (score 0):

Your `hover` function needs to be inside your `$(document).ready` function.

See my [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GntL/1/).

I have made another [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/2GntL/3/) to show you the same thing but with `.animate` instead of `.css` (even though it's totally irrelevant to the question).

Comment: Hi Billy, Thanks for this, im not sure how im going to apply it to my own example mind as im using an animate function rather than .css. But thanks for the example, i will see what i can do :)

Comment: It isn't to do with your animate function, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2GntL/3/) for updated version with animate instead of css. The problem is that your entire hover function needs to be inside `$(document).ready`